# How to use android media player play radio streaming in asx format

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I want to play this streaming url:

```
http://www.mediacorpradio.sg/radioliveplayer/asx/class95/fm950.asx
```

What I tried:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ...


    // player
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        }
    });
    try {
        player.setDataSource(radio_url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        toast("Unable to play this radio. Please email us if you see this constantly.");
        return;
    }

    player.prepareAsync();

}

private void toggleState(){
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.pause();
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    }else{
        player.prepareAsync();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    player.release();
}
```

Error I get:  (1, -1004)